# Saving/Fetching CoreData Relationships Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, relationship

I am making a budgeting app for the purposes of learning and I have a few questions about storing and fetching entities in CoreData.

I have two entities "Budget" and "Expense". 
[image]

Every Budget has its own Expenses. As an example I can have an 'Entertainment' budget and it can have expenses such as 'Bowling' and 'Movies' etc.

**I can create a Budget and save it. And then add expenses to it.**

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
let expense = Expense(context: context)
.
. // Filling out the expense here
.
budget?.addToExpense(expense)
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
```

**I then retrieve the collection of Expenses and display the store name in a TableView**

```
// Inside cellForRowAt
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
let myArray = Array((budget?.expense)!)
cell.textLabel?.text = (myArray[indexPath.row] as! Expense).store
return cell
```

So far so good. My issue is that when I store an expense it is stored in a Set. Which means the order is random when I retrieve that set and typecast it into an Array.

What I want is to store the Expenses and retrieve them in such a way that I can display the expenses in a FIFO order in the TableView. In other words the first expense I add in the budget should be the first element in the table view and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be several ways to achieve that. The most straightforward would be to use Ordered relation for `expense`.

To do that,

- Open `expense` relationship properties in DataModel editor.
- Check Ordered option

Then `budget.expense` will be not `Set`, but `OrderedSet`, and you won't need to convert it to `Array`, but access it directly by index.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

VIEWCONTROLLER  1:
=====================>

import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var txt_user: UITextField!





@IBOutlet weak var txt_password: UITextField!



var result = NSArray()



override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    txt_password.isSecureTextEntry = true

}







@IBAction func login_action(_ sender: Any)

{

   if(txt_user.text == "" || txt_password.text == "")

   {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "info", message: "fields are empty", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(ok)

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)



    }

    else

   {

    self.CheckForUserNameAndPasswordMatch(empName: txt_user.text! , empPwd: txt_password.text!)

    }





}



func CheckForUserNameAndPasswordMatch(empName:String,empPwd:String)

{

    let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context = app.persistentContainer.viewContext





    let fetchdata = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Employee")

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "empName = %@",empName)

    fetchdata.predicate = predicate

    do

    {

        self.result = try context.fetch(fetchdata as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)as NSArray

        if result.count>0

        {

            let objcetEntity = result.firstObject as! Employee





            if objcetEntity.empName == empName && objcetEntity.empPwd == empPwd

            {

                print("Login Successfully")

                // Entered Username & password matched

            }

            else

            {

                print("Wrong password/username")



                //Wrong password/username

            }



        }

    }

    catch let error as NSError

    {

        print("error",error.localizedDescription)

    }

}





 @IBAction func unwindToVC1(sender:UIStoryboardSegue)

 {

    if sender.source is ViewController2

    {

        let secvc = sender.source as! ViewController2

        txt_password.text = secvc.str1! as String

    }



}
```

VIEWCONTROLLER  2:

=====================>

class ViewController2: UIViewController ,UITextFieldDelegate{

```
@IBOutlet weak var txt_name: UITextField!



@IBOutlet weak var txt_mail: UITextField!



@IBOutlet weak var txt_pwd: UITextField!



@IBOutlet weak var txt_cpwd: UITextField!



@IBOutlet weak var txt_phone: UITextField!



@IBOutlet weak var err: UILabel!



var str1:NSString!

var str2:NSString!



//var update:NSManagedObject!







override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()



    /*if(update != nil)

    {

    txt_name.text = update.value(forKey: "empName") as? String

    txt_mail.text = update.value(forKey: "empMail") as? String

    txt_pwd.text = update.value(forKey: "empPwd") as? String

    txt_cpwd.text = update.value(forKey: "empCpwd") as? String

    txt_phone.text = update.value(forKey: "empPhone") as? String

    }*/



    txt_pwd.isSecureTextEntry = true

    txt_cpwd.isSecureTextEntry = true





}



override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)

{

    txt_name.becomeFirstResponder()

}









@IBAction func regis_clicked(_ sender: Any)

{



    if(txt_name.text == "" || txt_mail.text == "" || txt_pwd.text == "" || txt_cpwd.text == "" || txt_phone.text == "" )

    {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "information", message: "fields are empty", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler:

        {

           (actionsheet) in



            if(self.txt_name.text == "")

            {

                self.txt_name.becomeFirstResponder()

            }

            if(self.txt_mail.text == "")

            {

                self.txt_mail.becomeFirstResponder()

            }

            if(self.txt_pwd.text == "")

            {

                self.txt_pwd.becomeFirstResponder()

            }

            if(self.txt_cpwd.text == "")

            {

                self.txt_cpwd.becomeFirstResponder()

            }

            if(self.txt_phone.text == "")

            {

                self.txt_phone.becomeFirstResponder()

            }

        })



        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(ok)

        alert.addAction(cancel)



        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }



    else if(txt_pwd.text != txt_cpwd.text)

    {



        let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "information", message: "password mismatched", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler:nil)

        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)

        alert1.addAction(ok)

        alert1.addAction(cancel)

        self.present(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    else

    {



        let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate



        let context = app.persistentContainer.viewContext



        let newuser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Employee", into: context)

        newuser.setValue(txt_name.text, forKey: "empName")

        newuser.setValue(txt_mail.text, forKey: "empMail")

         newuser.setValue(txt_pwd.text, forKey: "empPwd")

         newuser.setValue(txt_cpwd.text, forKey: "empCpwd")

         newuser.setValue(txt_phone.text, forKey: "empPhone")



        do

        {

            try context.save()

        }

        catch let error as NSError

        {

            print("error",error.localizedDescription)

        }



    }

   // self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwind", sender: self)

}
```

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)

```
{

    if let newlabel = txt_pwd.text

    {

        str1 = newlabel as NSString

    }

}
```